# Add training data(text, melspectrogram, spectrogram, label(.wav) files) to Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, tensorflow2.0

1. How to add training data(text, melspectrogram, label(.wav)) in Tensorflow 2.0 like tutorials on Tensorflow website?
2. How to train that model with gradient tape in tf 2.0? I don't know what is the next step to do? I have built the model with layers with tf.keras.layers and tf.sequence_mask. I am replicating deep voice 3 model to do TTS.

```py
def model():
    def __init__(self):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            self.char2idx, self.idx2char = load_vocab()
            self.x, self.y1, self.y2, self.z, self.num_batch = get_batch()
            self.prev_max_attentions_li = tf.ones(shape=(hp.dec_layers, hp.batch_size), dtype=tf.int32)
            self.decoder_input = tf.concat((tf.zeros_like(self.y1[:, :1, -hp.n_mels:]), self.y1[:, :-1, -hp.n_mels:]), 1)
            self.keys, self.vals = Encoder(self.x)
            self.mel_logits, self.done_output, self.decoder_output, self.alignments_li, self.max_attentions_li = Decoder(self.decoder_input, self.keys, self.vals, self.prev_max_attentions_li)
            self.mel_output = tf.nn.sigmoid(self.mel_logits)
            self.converter_input = tf.reshape(self.decoder_output, (-1, hp.Ty, hp.char_embed//hp.r))
            self.converter_input = tf.keras.layers.Dense(hp.cchannel, activation = 'relu')(self.converter_input)
            self.mag_logits = Converter(self.converter_input)
            self.mag_output = tf.nn.sigmoid(self.mag_logits)
            self.global_step = tf.Variable(0, name='global_step', trainable=False)

            self.loss_mels = tf.reduce_mean(input_tensor=tf.abs(self.mel_output - self.y1))
            self.loss_dones = tf.reduce_mean(input_tensor=tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=self.done_output, labels=self.y2))
            self.loss_mags = tf.reduce_mean(input_tensor=tf.abs(self.mag_output - self.z))
            self.loss = self.loss_mels + self.loss_dones + self.loss_mags

            # Training Scheme
            self.optimizer = tf.keras.optimizer.Adam(lr=hp.lr)
            ## gradient clipping
            self.gvs = self.optimizer.compute_gradients(self.loss)
            self.clipped = []
            for grad, var in self.gvs:
                grad = tf.clip_by_value(grad, -1. * hp.max_grad_val, hp.max_grad_val)
                grad = tf.clip_by_norm(grad, hp.max_grad_norm)
                self.clipped.append((grad, var))
            self.train_op = self.optimizer.apply_gradients(self.clipped, global_step=self.global_step)

                # Summary
            tf.summary.scalar('Train_Loss/LOSS', self.loss)
            tf.summary.scalar('Train_Loss/mels', self.loss_mels)
            tf.summary.scalar('Train_Loss/dones', self.loss_dones)
            tf.summary.scalar('Train_Loss/mags', self.loss_mags)

            self.merged = tf.summary.merge_all()
```